# How do you ORDER BY two tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am what you would call a 'noob' at MySQL.  I can insert/edit/select stuff, but anything more advanced than that stumps me.  I have two tables in my database:

**Table 'reviews'**

```
id      int(11)
review  varchar(2500)
game    int(11)
user    int(11)
title   varchar(200)`
```

and **Table 'review_rating'**

```
user    int(11)
review  int(11)     // Corresponds to `reviews.id`
like    tinyint(1)
```

Here is my question: Is it possible to use `ORDER BY` on the `reviews` table to order the result by the total number of review_ratings with 'like' = 1 (where 'review' = the id of the 'reviews' table) divided by the total number of review_ratings (where 'review' = the id of the 'reviews' table).

Example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `reviews` 
WHERE `game` = ? 
ORDER BY (total number of review_ratings where review = reviews.id and like = 1 / 
         total number of review_ratings where review = reviews.id) 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: You don't have a table named "review". Don't expect "review.id" to resolve to anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  t.review,
        Score = CASE WHEN TotalReviews<> 0 THEN LikedReviews/TotalReviews ELSE NULL END
  FROM  (
              SELECT    *,
                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM review_rating WHERE review = r.review) AS TotalReviews ,
                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM review_rating WHERE review = r.review AND like = 1) AS LikedReviews,
              FROM  review r        
             WHERE  game = ?
         )t
ORDER BY t.review, Score
```

Comment: I got yours fixed up to this: http://pastebin.com/c9ps3L2j but now MySQL says "#1054 - Unknown column 'TotalReviews' in 'field list'"

Comment: Canyou try: Score = CASE WHEN t.TotalReviews<> 0 THEN t.LikedReviews/t.TotalReviews ELSE NULL END

Comment: Woot, it works :D I had to change a little of the code, but it works now. Here is the fully working code: http://pastebin.com/iJb0QeYu Anyways, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

I think it's clearer to put it in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT reviews.*,
       ( SELECT SUM(like) / COUNT(1)
           FROM review_ratings
          WHERE review = reviews.id
       ) like_ratio
  FROM reviews
 WHERE game = ?
 ORDER
    BY like_ratio DESC
 LIMIT 10
;
```

Notes:

- Not tested; I'm away from a MySQL box at the moment.
- I think you could move the subquery to the `ORDER BY` clause if you wanted, but it seems like a useful thing to retrieve, anyway.
- I'm not sure how the above will behave if a given review has no ratings. You may need to use a `CASE` expression to handle that situation.

Answer (score 0):

something like this would order by the total review_rating per review:

```
select( count(review.id) as 'total' from reviews join review_rating on review.id = review_rating.review group by review.id) order by total
```

the math is not exactly what you had but hopefully you will get it